# Jquery Mobile not working?

Tags: jquery-mobile

In my project , I am using Asp.net and j query mobile. Now I am using jquery.mobile-1.0b3.css in my pro. I wanna update my jquery mobile new version.

But latest jquery.mobile-1.0.1 has four css files. What I want to add?.

```
    > jquery.mobile-1.0.1.css 
jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css
    > jquery.mobile.structure-1.0.1.css
    > jquery.mobile.structure-1.0.1.min.css
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are two files with a minified version each.

The file without the `.min.` is commonly used in production as it is smaller in size than it's un-minified version.

The un-minified version is used in development to debug issues that may arrise.

***More Information on the topic:***

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheImportanceAndEaseOfMinifyingYourCSSAndJavaScriptAndOptimizingPNGsForYourBlogOrWebsite.aspx

Local ***development*** references:

```
<link rel="stylesheet"jquery.mobile-1.0.1.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet"jquery.mobile.structure-1.0.1.css" />
```

Deployed to ***production*** references:

```
<link rel="stylesheet"jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet"jquery.mobile.structure-1.0.1.min.css" />
```

Comment: to make it very easy a "minified" version is the same as original but it is a compressed version where all functions/variables are changed to be very short so that filesize is much smaller. The source code of that file is not an easy file to read when you are debuggin your code but it does exactly the same job as non-minified.